# React Native: POST Request Works in Development but Not in EAS Build APK

Tags: android, react-native, request, expo, eas

I'm facing an issue with my React Native app where a POST request works perfectly when I run the app using npx expo start, but it doesn't work as expected when I build the APK using EAS Build and install it on my Android device.

In my app, I have a button labeled "Done" and when this button is pressed, it sends a POST request to a server and should display the response text below the button. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// ...imports and other code...

const TypeScreen = () => {
  const [mole, setMole] = useState('');
  const [responseText, setResponseText] = useState('');

  const sendPostRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const ipAddress = '/*IP*/';
      const port = '/*PORT*/';
      const endpoint = `http://${ipAddress}:${port}/`;

      const requestBody = {
        "key1": mole
      }; 

      const json = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

      const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: json,
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseText = await response.text();
        console.log('POST request successful');
        console.log('Response Text: ', responseText);
        setResponseText(responseText);
      } else {
        console.error('POST request failed with status:', response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending POST request:', error);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    // ...other components and UI...
    <TouchableOpacity 
      style={styles.btnPurple}
      onPress={sendPostRequest}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonTextWhite}>Done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonTextPurple}>Response:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.buttonTextPurple}>{responseText}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have already checked for network connectivity and reviewed the EAS Build logs, but I'm unsure why the behavior differs between development and production builds. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CORS issue?   What are the endpoint/port?  Any errors in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the web tools also aren't showing any results.
Here are the endpoint and port: '54.198.38.242' '5000'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Was coming off a react question and this is RN.  CORS doesn't appy.

Comment: Thank you anyways! I now noticed that the web tools aren't working as well. so I've got another clue to what could be happening.

Comment: Ok.  The code looks ok.  Good luck